# Number of memcache connections never drops, keeps growing

Tags: php, memcached

We've set up three memcache servers for our web application.

Two are doing fine, handling tens of thousands of reads and writes, all while maintaining no more than 12 connections each (according to [memcache-top](http://code.google.com/p/memcache-top/)).

We have a third memcache server which is responsible for storing administrative client session data (using [PHPs built in memcache session handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.examples-overview.php#memcache.examples-overview)) and some random application data. For some reason the number of connections on this box never goes down, only increasing over time. For example, we recently restarted the server and an hour later memcache-top records ~300 connections.

The code base uses a mixture of persistent connections and dynamic connections, but I have been unable to come up with a simple example for recreating the situation where connections never die. This third memcache server actually hosts the least active portion of our web application, as you can see from memcache-top:

```
memcache-top v0.6  (default port: 11211, color: on, refresh: 3 seconds)

INSTANCE         USAGE  HIT %  CONN  TIME   EVICT/s READ/s  WRITE/s  
memcache1:11211  15.7%  83.5%    10  1.2ms      0.0  24.9K    34.5K  
memcache2:11211  15.8%  81.3%    10  1.0ms      0.0  19.1K    31.6K  
memcache3:11211  0.1%   0.0%    354  1.1ms      0.0      4      321  

AVERAGE:    10.5%  55.0%  124  1.1ms  0.0  14.7K  22.1K  

TOTAL:    0.6GB/  6.0GB    374  3.2ms  0.0  44.0K  66.4K
```

So my question is: Why do the connections for this memcache instance never die?

Comment: Q1. Does that 3rd "troublesome" server happen to be a *BSD, while those 2 "fine" servers - Linux? Q2. What is the CPU use % for all 3 memcaches?

Answer (score 4):

Persistent connections in PHP will allocate a connection for every apache worker process.  Is Apache setup to allow ~354 worker processes?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using PHP5? Most likely yes. Here's a possible pitfall from the [PHP session_set_save_handler documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php):

> As of PHP 5.0.5 the write and close
>   handlers are called after object
>   destruction and therefore cannot use
>   objects or throw exceptions. The
>   object destructors can however use
>   sessions.
>
> It is possible to call
>   session_write_close() from the
>   destructor to solve this chicken and
>   egg problem.

How much do you want to bet the memcache session handler hasn't been revisited since before this change? As a solution or at least diagnostic, I recommend writing your own memcached session open/close/read/write and destroy functions (not object), hook them up with session_set_save_handler and skip using the built-in one. At the very least you'll be able to log the internals then.

Comment: As a side note to logging/debugging your custom session handler - You'll need to use something along the lines of **file_put_contents()** as the write() method occurs after content has been flushed to the page.

Answer (score 1):

What are your session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor set to ?
Some Linux distributions overwrite these values and add a cronjob to clear sessions. Your problem may be caused by this behavior.